# wrong using variable in regexp

Tags: c#, regex

I need to achieve such output list:

```
Zone1 
Zone7
Zone2
```

from this strings:

set zone "Zone1" vrouter "trust-vr"

set zone "Zone3" vrouter "Untrust-vr"

set zone "Zone7" vrouter "trust-vr"

set zone "Zone2" vrouter "trust-vr"

set zone "Zone4" vrouter "Untrust-vr"

To do this, I have code:

```
                foreach (string v in vr)
            {
                string pattern = @"set zone ""([\w-]+)"" (vrouter)"+v;


                var myCollection =
                    Regex.Matches(reader1.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                        .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                        .Distinct();

                foreach (string match in myCollection)
                {
                    txt1.Text += match + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
```

I think that i do not correct use the variable *v* in pattern regexp , because withoute this variable code works as it should but output all zones. But I need only ones for vrouter with name of this variable.

Comment: Do you need quotes around `v`?

Comment: You are missing a space after `(vrouter)`

Comment: I do not need in ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string pattern = @"set zone ""([\w-]+)"" vrouter """+v;
```

(assuming v holds strings like trust or Untrust)

Comment: I missed the last " - answer edited. What are the values in `vr`?

Comment: All fine now! At least the regular expression is true!

Comment: @user3214034,check out my answer too